# Linux filesystem million symlinks vs million files

Tags: linux, caching, symlink

I'm working on a Linux filesystem-based caching system for a web application to be used as a last resort when APC and Memcache are unavailable.  The system will cache between 500,000 and 1,000,000 unique strings identifiers, each with a large value.  I'm taking the MD5 hash of the string ID and based on the first few chars, creating subfolders so not too many files end up in any one directory.

I know this concepts works because I'm using it in a similar application.

Although there are up to 1MM string IDs, they all point one of only 18,000 unique values, so, for instance there might be 100,000 string IDs that all point to the same value.  Right now this means there are 100,000 files with different filenames containing the same content which is bad for the underlying filesystem cache.

Is there any disadvantage to caching the 18,000 unique values, then for every unique string ID, creating a symlink to the unique value file?  This way the filesystem buffer can cache the 18,000 files and the descriptors for the symlinks.

I'm just concerned about having 1,000,000 symlinks and any potential problems this may introduce.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compared to storing plain files, no there is no disadvantage to storing symlinks. Performance will be slightly slower because of the indirection, *but* dentries and inodes are cached too.

However, I strongly suggest you need **hard** links, because that way, the content will stay around until the last of the links is deleted.

Comment: Good point.  Plus with hard links I can invalidate the entire cache by deleting all the actual files, correct?

Comment: Yes, but once the links are made they are indistinguishable from the original, so there is no "master link". OTOH, you can certainly invalidate an individual cache *key* by just deleting the one link.

Comment: This fine in my application because if any entry is invalid they are all invalid.  I did a quick test to see symbolic vs. hard links:

test.txt is a real file, _s is symbolic and _h is hard.  I can see that hard links share the same inode, so I would think this would be very efficient as opposed to symbolic links, just like you said.

`5816577 -rw-r--r--  2 root root       5 Jul  7 11:22 test.txt
5816577 -rw-r--r--  2 root root       5 Jul  7 11:22 test_h.txt
5816578 lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       8 Jul  7 11:22 test_s.txt -> test.txt`

Sorry - markdown sucks in comments apparently

Answer (score 1):

I agree with [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe), and please also note that hard links will use **only 18,000 inodes** instead of **10<sup>6</sup>**; a hard link only uses an additional directory entry that points to the one and only inode. You will save *10<sup>6</sup>* * *inode size* bytes on-disk and in your memory cache.

Comment: Great, thanks for the confirmation.  Do you know how the relationship between actual filename and inode is made by chance?